# "Message Not Sent."

Tags: sms

I'm on Edge connection because I have a third party device which I love. It's pretty fast most of the time, but today I think something happened. Android (4.2) keeps telling me "Message Not Sent" whenever I try sending a text. I even whiped my phone and it's still happening.. Like I said, it's on Edge but most of the time it isn't that slow. Not like this, at least. Why do I keep getting that error message?

I open Dolphin Browser, goes straight to any URL I type in. Weird that texts specifically are acting strange. Quite slow, but at least it works. Texts don't.

Comment: "SMS Service Center" in text message app.is blank when I tap it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a bunch. How do I mark your answer as "best"?

Comment: There, since that did turn out to be the problem, I've made it into an answer. I didn't at first because it was a bit of a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your situation, the most likely cause is that the *message centre* is not set correctly. First, find out the correct setting from your carrier: it's probably on their website, or you can phone their support line and ask. Once you know the correct setting, find the *message centre* option in the settings for the stock SMS app, and set it correctly.